# Can I pay for my Turkish visa on arrival at the airport in Euros?

Tags: visas, money, turkey, visas-on-arrival, isl

I'm Australian, flying into Istanbul Turkey tomorrow (Ataturk airport) and I know from last year's trip that I must pay a visa fee upon entry. But last year I crossed by land from Bulgaria and this year I'm flying in from Korea.

I didn't manage to change any money for Turkish Lira beforehand but I did manage to change some for Euros which I hoped would ease a few situations where I wouldn't have the correct local currency.

Does anyone know if this fee can be paid in Euros, and if so will they give me change in Euros or Lira? Is the price higher if paying in a currency other than Lira? If I can't pay in Euros, is there a chance to access an ATM in the airport before the point the fee must be paid?

Comment: Which airport? And which nationality are you [I paid in Sterling]?

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a booth for changing money just before passport control, in case they don't accept euros.

Comment: In case you don't find an exchange booth, I think you can also go to the Duty-Free, buy some chocolate, pay in Euros, and ask to get change in Liras. Although they may rip you off on the exchange rate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The visas used to be 15€ or 20$, and paying in Turkish liras was not an option. There was an ATM right next to the visa booth. However, as of the 10th of April this year, visas are now applied- and paid for online at https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/. EU citizens can get the visa at electronic booths in the airport, but getting it online prior to arrival is cheaper.

Comment: [on the Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) it says starting the 17th of April

Answer (score 12):

You can pay in EUR or USD (cash-only), the price schedule is posted in both currencies [(link)](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/details/BorderFormalities/).

Comment: In fact you can **only** pay in `EUR` or `USD`! I just entered Turkey via the Greek land border the other day and had enough `TRY`, Turkish Lira, but not enough Euro. They made me change some lira to euro so I could pay!

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that they want visas paid for in the currency used by your country. I know the US visas have to be purchased in dollars not Euros. I have seen lists of currency posted for different countries and their visa costs/currencies, but I don't remember Australia's.

Comment: There's a difference between *can* be and *must* be. Someone might need to confirm this.

Comment: I can only say for certain that it *used* to be that you could only buy the US Visas in dollars. That doesn't mean it's that way still or that it applies to other countries.

Comment: I was given the option at the airport of paying in US dollars or in Euro. Since I was able to get some Euro from friends at home before my trip but not US dollars I paid in Euro. At this moment it works out a tiny bit cheaper in dollars.